# Overlaying data points from different data frames using ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a density scatter plot and want to add some data point with extra information on that. I can plot the `first data frame`, but have problem overlaying the `second` one. Here is an example:

```
library(ggplot2)

a <- runif(20000,min=-20,max=20)
b <-  runif(20000,min=200,max=600)
df1 <- data.frame(a=a , b=b ,c =densCols(a, b, colramp = colorRampPalette(rev(rainbow(20000, end = 4/6)))))
df2 <- data.frame(a= runif(50,min=-20,max=20), b= runif(50,min=200,max=600), d=runif(50,min=-1,max=1))

ggplot(df1) +
geom_point(aes(a, b, col = c), size = 1) + scale_color_identity() + 
geom_point(data=df2,aes(a, b,col = d, size=d)) +
scale_color_gradient2(limits=c(-1, 1), low="red" , high="blue", space = "Lab")
```

adding the `df2` creates error: `invalid argument to unary operator`.

I am also interested to know how to create the density scatter plot smoother, so that it can cover the entire plot area.

Comment: You can't supply two color scales; one will override the other. In this case, you can just do `ggplot(df1) +
    geom_point(aes(a, b), col = df1$c, size = 1) + 
    geom_point(data=df2,aes(a, b,col = d, size=d)) +
    scale_color_gradient2(limits=c(-1, 1), low="red" , high="blue", space = "Lab")` You should really look at ggplot's 2d density geoms, though, like `geom_hex`, `geom_bin2d`, and `geom_density2d`.

Comment: the error message is not the one you quote

Comment: @baptiste with the code suggested by alistaire, I don't the error massage, but I wanted to find a way to smooth the colors.